# Rails 3.1 Capybara jQuery is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I keep on getting this error:

```
 Failure/Error: page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active') == 0
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError:
   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

whenever I use the script:

```
wait_until do
  page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active') == 0
end
```

I've put in a debugger and checked for the jQuery library. It was existing on the particular page.

Is there something I need to configure for this to work?

EDIT:

Versions of Capybara and RSpec are:

rspec-rails-2.11.0
rspec-2.11.0
capybara-1.1.2

Comment: What version of rspec/capybara are you using? Actually, *is* this rspec you're running this in, or cucumber, or something else?

Comment: it is rspec but using capybara in it.

Answer (score 1):

The error implies your example does have js:true, but it would be good to post a complete example here.

I found that switching from the default selenium driver to webkit solved a few different issues for me, and also examples run much faster.

Not an answer, per se, but it's worth trying to see if it solves your particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  I solved it by dropping a binding.pry in the test and stopping the selenium browser.  Upon inspection, I noticed that the js console had thrown errors: Selenium could not find a .js file.

The root of the problem was an outdated rails test application preloaded with spring.  I had installed a gem (moment-timezone-rails) but was still continuing to run my tests with 'spring rspec,' which didn't have the proper directory to find the js file.

restarting spring fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with FF 41.0.2 and capybara-webkit 3.4.0. After upgrading FF to 53.0.3 the issue has gone

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually seen when **`jQuery.active`** return **true** or **false** in place of 0 & 1. Especially in the case of page transition. For ex: from signin page to home page.

A sample execution log that will help you understand the page transition behaviour. Here on the sign-in page, user creds are provided and post successful validation redirected to home page :

```
2022-10-12 14:43:45,887 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] Waiting for Page Javascript to load completely
2022-10-12 14:43:45,917 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] document.readyState value is : complete
2022-10-12 14:43:45,929 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] jQuery.active value is : 0
2022-10-12 14:43:46,030 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] Waiting for Page Javascript to load completely
2022-10-12 14:43:46,036 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] document.readyState value is : loading
2022-10-12 14:43:46,042 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] jQuery.active value is : false
2022-10-12 14:43:48,725 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] Waiting for Page Javascript to load completely
2022-10-12 14:43:48,731 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] document.readyState value is : complete
2022-10-12 14:43:48,737 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] jQuery.active value is : false
2022-10-12 14:53:37,299 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] document.readyState value is : complete
2022-10-12 14:53:37,305 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] jQuery.active value is : 1
2022-10-12 14:53:37,407 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] Waiting for Page Javascript to load completely
2022-10-12 14:53:37,416 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] document.readyState value is : complete
2022-10-12 14:53:37,421 INFO console.base.seleniumHelperUtil [main] jQuery.active value is : 0
```

In order to overcome this problem, you will have to add a check of **window.jQuery != undefined**

So your code should be something like :

```
wait_until do
  page.evaluate_script('window.jQuery') != undefined && page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active') == 0
end
```